# How to return a range of cells based on a value in the adjacent column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, textjoin

I'd like to write a formula to such that it returns a range of cells from column H (unique ID) based on a criterion that is the value in column G (parent manual id). So for e.g. the formula should return a range of all the cells highlighted in yellow (from the image below) when the criteria in the adjacent column (column G) is 1. Similarly, the formula should return a range of all the cells highlighted in blue when the criterion (column G) is 2, and so on.

The reason, I need this to be a range of cells, is because I need to pass this resultant range as an argument into another formula (a TEXTJOIN function).

[image: Reference table]

Answer (score 2):

Use a query function. Make a helper column I with all unique parent manual ids column G --> `unique(G2:G)`

Then for the textjoin column:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,QUERY(G$2:$H,"SELECT H WHERE G="&I2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this out.

Answer (score 0):

use `FILTER`

```
=FILTER(H:H; G:G=1)
```

and:

```
=FILTER(H:H; G:G=2)
```

and then do your `TEXTJOIN` for csv:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", "; 1; FILTER(H:H; G:G=1))
```

or perhaps for regex:

```
=TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; FILTER(H:H; G:G=2))
```